# C++ How to compare classes

Tags: c++

I have a small question. Let's say I have

```
Character char1;
Character char2;
```

What's the best way to compare if all the member class variables are the same? Can I use memcmp for it? I'm kinda new to this memory stuff, so thanks everyone for help.

Comment: Definition of `Character`?

Comment: What is a `Character`? Is this your own type? How does it behave? What kind of members does it have? This question is very unclear

Comment: It would have many variables, pointers, it's an class, sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: You need to include the needed information. For example, the answer would be **very** different for `class`es that have pointer members and for the ones that do not

Comment: `operator==` is usually the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `memcmp`.

The normal way is to write you own equality operator.

As a non-member it would look like

```
bool operator==(const Character& lhs, const Character& rhs)
{
    return lhs.member1 == rhs.member1 
        && lhs.member2 == rhs.member2 
        && ...
}
```